# Symfony framework: Common method for multiple modules

Tags: methods, symfony1, module

In my project I have multiple modules as:
1. Become sponsor
2. Become exhibitor
3. Call for papers
4. Etc

In these modules I have a form for users to fill and submit data. It's like a registration form. If registration is succeeded, I send "welcome message" to user's email. This email template is common for all situations!
So, I need a common function, method to call in order to send that email. I don't want to write it in each action. So that, in that method I could get instance of mailer, user culture etc, like in a basic module action.
Please help, brothers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new class in your `lib` directory.

The file will automatically included in your action files.

Then in your action:

```
$obj = new YourNewClass();
$obj->sendMail($p1, $p2, ...);
```

Comment: How can I include it in other modules? Can you give simple example of that class?

Comment: By default, classes stored in the following directories in your projects benefit from the autoloading automatically:

myproject/lib/
myproject/lib/model
myproject/apps/myapp/lib/
myproject/apps/myapp/modules/mymodule/lib

Then your class should send the mail based on some params. But this is another subject?!